# Help with deploying a model

Tags: machine-learning, software

The two main packages I use at work are Palisade Risk and SPSS Clementine - they are both quite old versions and I've been supplementing the ability to analyze properly at work with more modern abilities available at home. E .g.at home I've been testing RapidMiner 5, which I really like in principle but have experienced a few issues with large data sets whereby the computational time progresses for hours then crashes for yet unknown reasons.

What I like about Palisade & Clementine is they seem quite robust in ability to handle large amounts of input data and more importantly the ability to easily deploy models, i.e. once we have a model(s) that works we just feed it raw data and the outputs are predicted. However, Palisade & SPSS are both very limited in modern stats methods and machine learning algorithms that are hugely behind methods available in R/RapidMiner (Eg cross validation to name one). I would really like to convince my company to invest in R/Rapidminer but the ease of deployment of models is really the crux of the problem. May I ask how easy or difficult it is to achieve model deployment in the following and ask any advice from fellow professionals?

i) RapidMiner
ii) R
iii) other recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R/Rapidminer are free. Deployment can get tricky if you are concerned about multiple GB datasets, but other than that, everything is a breeze. RStudio on a linux server has been getting great reviews, and Revolution Analytics sells an enterprise version of R at a very reasonable cost with a focus on enhanced deployability, big data, fancy UI, and data export to make R more accessible to the non-statistician.